# Hyperonyme dont le sens réfère au cinéma, au théâtre, à l'opéra, au ballet, au mime, à la pantomime, …

Tags: vocabulaire

Lorsqu'on parle de l'ensemble des arts que sont la peinture, le dessin, la sculpture, la photographie et d'autres, on emploie le terme « *art(s) figuratif* ».  Existerait-il un terme en un seul mot par lequel on pourrait référer à l'ensemble des manifestations artistiques que sont   le cinéma, le théâtre, l'opéra, le ballet, le mime, la pantomime, etc. ? À défaut trouve-t-on  une expression usuelle, qui comprendrait probablement la forme « arts » mais pas nécessairemment ? Autrement quelqu'un aurait-il une idée de formulation d'une expression concise pour pallier ce manque de terme ?

Comment: Les arts plastiques: Voici un bon article sur ce sujet: https://www.superprof.fr/ressources/art-loisir/arts-menagers/cours-arts3/tous-niveaux-arts3/explication-termes-artistiques.html

Comment: @Lambie Ce terme inclu bien le cinéma, mais pas le théâtre, ni le ballet, et puis il n'est pas assez restrictif.

Comment: @LPH Je n'avais jamais entendu *art plastique* utilisé pour le cinéma. Les arts plastiques, c'est pour moi surtout la peinture, sculpture, collages, etc.

Comment: Arts de la scène, arts scéniques (tout ce qui se présente sur une scène), J'avais oublié de le dire. Le cinéma, le septìème art.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, c'est la scène, c'est bien mieux.

Comment: @Lambie You are thinking about "performing arts" probably, but that includes music, and entails live performances. https://www.cairn.info/economie-des-arts-et-de-la-culture--9782200277413-page-97.htm

Comment: These: le cinéma, le théâtre, l'opéra, le ballet, le mime, la pantomime, etc. are misgrouped.   **le théâtre, l'opéra, le ballet, le mime, la pantomime,** are together. Le cinéma is not there. So, without cinéma: arts de la scène is right. Le cinéma est à part.

Comment: @Lambie Misgrouped…  yes, as far as is concerned this particular classification  you choose, but the performing arts include musical performances, which are not manifestations in which some sort of a story is developped through the bias of people (also moppets and the like) who are seen in motion and impersonating characters, and this is typical of the cinema, which because of that has to be included.

Comment: No, LPH: No one ever places film with other stage performance forms.  Why are  you now talking about performing arts in ENGLISH?? You said: le théâtre, l'opéra, le ballet, le mime, la pantomime, etc. So don't go changing it in mid-stream.

Comment: @Lambie Don't forget the cinema.

Comment: Le cinéma is film in English, not cinema. Film is the seventh art. Le cinéma, c'est le septième art. British English: We went to the cinema last night. American English: We went to the movies last night.

Comment: @Lambie No, you are only considering American English! SOED, **cinema** Cinematography,; the production of  cinematographic films, esp. as an art or as an industry. // ex. At the same time, it set the trend for filming opera scenes as a guarantor of success for the cinema in China, where a vast array of classical stories that came from oral tradition, moved to literature and then to opera,  https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Cinema_of_Jia_Zhangke/6gaZDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+cinema%22&pg=PA156&printsec=frontcover

Comment: No, I am not; I am considering **preferred usage**. This is the UK: Why study this course?
The **Theatre and Film** BA merges cinematic and performance languages, explored through practice and theory. Develop the skills required for successful employment opportunities within the international film and television industries, and within theatre and performing arts. https://www.londonmet.ac.uk/courses/undergraduate/theatre-and-film---ba-hons/

Comment: UK: Drama with Film BA///https://www.royalholloway.ac.uk/studying-here/undergraduate/drama-theatre-and-dance/drama-with-film/ Film studies, film. NOT cinema. //That book was from a non-English speaker who also translated some book she called: On Cinema. The term cinéma in French is film or films in English. Not the cinema, usually. Including in the UK.

Comment: It is not a fancy:  études de cinéma = **film studies**, no doubt about it. Traditional practices?

Comment: @Lambie Won't you read? SOED : esp. as an art. Given ex. : 2019.

Comment: UK special JUST FOR YOU: **Film, also called movie, motion picture or moving picture**, is a visual art-form used to simulate experiences that communicate ideas, stories, perceptions, feelings or beauty, or atmosphere through the use of moving images. These images are generally accompanied by sound, and more rarely, other sensory simulations. **The word 'cinema', short for cinematography, is often used to refer to filmmaking and the film industry, and to the art form that is the result of it.** https://www.satro.org.uk/film

Comment: @Lambie You've got to be joking! What do you make of this page of examples where "the cinema" means "cinematographic art? Check it out, please, for your own information, and verify how recent are the publishing dates so as to make yourself awware of how well  preserved is this usage.  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20cinema%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en And again and first of all **ep. as art** (the cinema of Clint Eastwood).

Comment: I'm not joking. That is a perfectly respectable British site. **The word 'cinema', short for cinematography, is often used to refer to filmmaking and the film industry. It is a major film school**.  "British cinema is alive and well"=The British film industry is alive and well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134074/discussion-between-oreste-and-lph).

Answer (score 7):

On pourrait parler de **scène**, des **planches**, du **spectacle vivant** mais ce dernier exclut le cinéma.

En revanche, les **arts du spectacle** ne l'excluent pas (cf. intermittents du spectacle).

Comment: spectacle ne marche pas très bien pour moi. Ça fait trop show "à vedette".

Comment: @Lambie C'est assez vrai, le Concours Eurovision de la chanson est un spectacle mais ce n'est pas dans la classification à laquelle je pense et dans laquelle on trouverait le spectacle de marionnettes aussi bien que celui des dessins animés.

Comment: @LPH J'ai peur qu'aucun terme générique ne puisse précisément coller avec ta sélection qui semble de manière plus ou moins arbitraire ou du moins personnelle exclure ou inclure certains formes de spectacle.

Comment: @Lambie "Ça fait trop show "à vedette"." Imho you and LPH are projecting English language semantics onto that. It's more show/performance/exhibition, it need not be over the top or Broadway. Things like _arts du spectacle_ have a long [standing](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8457100) in the French language. They're here to stay.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille Fyi, spectacle is also used in Portuguese and Spanish, just like in French. I prefer art scèniques, which, by the way, is the first term in your Termium citation. Here are the terms: arts de la scène   n. m. pl.

arts d'interprétation   n. m. pl.

arts du spectacle   n. m. pl.

représentations artistiques   n. f. pl.

Comment: @Lambie *Art scénique* n'est souvent d'abord qu'un jeu de mot sur arsenic. Contrairement à ce que tu as écrit, cette forme n'apparaît ni sur Termium+ (que Ti-cul Ti-caille n'a pas cité) ni sur l'OQLF.

Comment: **spectacle in English** is a **major faux ami** with French, Spanish and Portuguese (where they all mean the same thing!!). In English, we say: He made a spectacle of himself at the party yesterday.

Comment: @Lambie Pas nécessairement un faux-ami : *He made a spectacle of himself at the party yesterday* →  *Il s'est donné en spectacle à la soirée d'hier*.

Comment: @jlliagre It is in general a faux ami. J'ai assisté au spectacle à 18h hier soir. NOT spectacle.  Show. I went to the show at 8 pm last night.

Comment: **Les arts de la scène** comprennent : le théâtre, la danse, la musique et la chanson. Ensemble, ils forment un circuit solide et dynamique qui compte plus d'une centaine d'organismes, diffuseurs pluridisciplinaires et réseaux de diffuseurs pluridisciplinaires, répartis sur tout le territoire québécois. La vitalité du circuit stimule **la circulation de spectacles** à travers le Québec, [tu vois?] Là oui. Voilà, mon point de vue. ou spectacles veut dire shows en anglais. Une excellente rédaction, à mon humble avis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134052/discussion-between-lambie-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score -2):

Sur la base d'une [réponse antérieure](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49722/17649) qui ne donnerait à mon avis qu'un résultat partiel (*arts du spectacle*) il devient possible de proposer un terme qui combine deux notions déjà identifiées dans la langue actuelle, celle de « *arts du spectacle* » et celle de « *spectacle narratif* » ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spectacle+narratif&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspectacle%20narratif%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cspectacle%20narratif%3B%2Cc0)) pour produire la notion ***des arts du spectacle narratif*** , laquelle, si [elle n'existe pas](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arts+du+spectacle+narratif&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=) encore, semble remplir  comme un gant une case vide qui n'attendait qu'à servir.

Le terme « spectacle narratif » ne se trouve pas dans les dictionnaires courants ni sur la Toile mais c'est un terme quasiment auto-défini et  déjà reconnu dans la littérature concernant les arts, comme le montre l'ngram en référence ci-dessus et la page des exemples qui y sont associés ([exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spectacle%20narratif%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)). Bien que la liste de ces arts ne soit pas disponible, il semble qu'il y a peu de difficulté à décider si un art donné y figure ou non. Il est par exemple clair que le cinéma doit y figurer.

- ([réf. 1, 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_fictions_de_jeunesse/YjNKDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22spectacle+narratif%22&pg=PT41&printsec=frontcover)) L'effet spécial n'a de sens qu'au regard de l'immersion fictionnelle qu'il favorise ; il ne saurait être une prouesse gratuite parce qu'il n'est qu'un élément du spectacle narratif que donne le film. Par ces procédés, le cinéma à grand …

De même la pantomime en fait partie.

- ([réf. 2, 2014](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Th%C3%A9%C3%A2tre_Pour_les_Nuls/ol5QAwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22spectacle+narratif%22&pg=PT228&printsec=frontcover)) Ils'adosse à la pantomime, spectacle narratif, tout en gestes, généralement accompagné de musique. George Sand témoigna toute son admiration à l'un des mimes de son temps, Charles Deburau,

Le specgacle des marionnettes n'y fait pas défaut.

- ([réf. 3, 2014](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Passages_de_la_prose_po%C3%A9sie_d%C3%A9voy%C3%A9e/71onDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22spectacle+narratif%22&pg=PT138&printsec=frontcover)) la théâtralisation du recueil alors que les personnages des contes peuvent, par un effet de lecture rétrospectif, être appréhendés comme des marionnettes au sein du spectacle narratif proposé par le livre entier.

On y trouve bien sûr les spectacles de la « grande » scène cités dans le PO ;
le ballet d'action entre dans cette catégorie sans problème.

- ([réf. 4, Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballet_d%27action)) Le ballet d'action ou ballet-pantomime est un spectacle chorégraphique narratif, dont l'histoire est développée à l'aide de la danse et de la pantomime. Il naît au XVIIIe siècle, sous l'influence de l'opéra-ballet et de la comédie-ballet que Lully, Molière et Beauchamp avaient portés sur les scènes d'Europe durant le règne de Louis XIV.

L'opéra a aussi sa place.

- ([réf. 5, 2006](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/%C5%92uvres_compl%C3%A8tes_de_Michel_Butor_Reche/BrM_AQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22spectacle+narratif%22&dq=%22spectacle+narratif%22&printsec=frontcover)) Ce peut être dans un spectacle narratif comme L'Histoire du soldat ou certaines scènes d'opéra comme la fin du premier acte de Don Juan . Dans le concert traditionnel les musiciens tiennent toute la place , qu'ils soient chanteurs ou …

On ne voit pas comment on aurait pu exclure le théâtre et la référence suivante montre qu'il n'y a aucun problème pour le porter sur la liste.

- ([réf. 6, 1987](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Roman/a6crAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22spectacle+narratif%22&dq=%22spectacle+narratif%22&printsec=frontcover)) Et ce qu'on retient d'un spectacle narratif , théâtre ou cinéma , c'est finalement une voix exprimée par d'autres voix qui parviennent à trouver le ton de la première sans perdre pour autant leur singularité.

Des formes très diverses de spectacle sont plus ou moins facilement identifiées comme faisant partie du spectacle narratif, par exemple le *concert party* ([aussi « Pierrot troupe » en anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concert_party_(entertainment))), au Togo.

- ([réf. 2, 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Ebrahim_Hussein/Vs2oDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22spectacle+narratif%22&pg=PT28&printsec=frontcover)) Le concert party au Togo est une forme de spectacle narratif, une tradition orale jouée et chantée, qui propose des récits de la vie urbaine contemporaine : des histoires de famille en ville (Ricard, 1987).

Je ne trouve aucune référence pour le dessin animé, cependant il me semble évident que cette forme d'art fournit un spectacle narratif.

On pourrait ainsi dire que le cinéma est le plus grand des arts du spectacle narratif ou le plus grand des spectacles narratifs.

Comment: le cinéma, le théâtre, l'opéra, le ballet, le mime, la pantomime,//ballet et mime sont narratifs?

Comment: @Lambie Ça me semble plutôt évident, vu le sens le plus simple que l'on puisse donner au terme « spectacle narratif » et vu les exemples d'usage que l'on trouve. Pour ce qui est du ballet il faudrait se limiter au ballet d'action (Le Lac des Cygnes, Casse-Noisette). Il me semble cependant que vous ne lisez pas sérieusement l'information qui se trouve dans mes commentaires et ma réponse : ce que je viens de dire s'en déduit.